# How can I use Visual Studio Code's F12 Go to Definition feature to view implementations of common NodeJS methods such as `setTimeout`?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

How can I use Visual Studio Code's F12 Go to Definition feature to view implementations of common NodeJS methods such as `setTimeout`?

This is currently not the default behavior. Instead of taking me to the NodeJS implementation of `setTimeout` as found on [GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js#L140), it takes me to [unhelpful TypeScript symbol definitions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18667) from Microsoft's TypeScript repository with 0 function body, documentation, nor parameters even. You can see the current behavior in this [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4NHq.png)

Like most developers who are using NodeJS, I currently have to either go to NodeJS's GitHub repository or nodejs.org to obtain any decent documentation or implementation.

It would be helpful for me, and most developers, to know how to easily access documentation and implementation with a F12 button press.

Note: This is not just a VS Code question, but for any IDE when developing NodeJS applications such as Atom or similar.